# Use React Native (0.60.4) in an iOS Share Extension

Tags: ios, react-native, share-extension

As the title implies, I tried to load a React Native application (version 0.60.4) in my native iOS Share Extension but got the following error: `sharedApplication is unavailable: not available on iOS (App Extension)`

[image: sharedApplication is unavailable: not available on iOS (App Extension)]
It seems React-Core (and other libraries like FBSDK) are using sharedApplication which isn't known inside the Share Extension 'architecture'?

I have tried using [this sample](https://github.com/andrewsardone/react-native-ios-share-extension) project but it doesn't compile out of the box.
It uses React Native v0.15 which perhaps worked at the time.

Does anyone have an idea how to implement the latest React Native version inside an iOS Share Extension?

Comment: Any update on this?

Comment: No sorry, I haven't found a working example for this and ended up not implementing the share extension on iOS in React Native. If you find a solution for this, I would be happy to hear it!

Comment: @Jovan Have you tried Reinstalled `cocoapods`, then reinstalled all pods.